# Ayuda con Qt creator , no permite correr proyectos?

Tags: python, c++, qt, c++11, qt-creator

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]la verdad he instalado varias veces el qt creator pero nunca me había costado tanto como en mi actual pc; primero usé el instalador que siempre llevaba en mi pendrive (el de qt 5.8 ), me decía que no podía descargar ciertos repositorios, descargué la version 5.9 del mismo instalador, con el mismo resultado. Después de intentar instalarlo varias veces y que no cargara fui a otra casa donde logré instalarlo, aunque tuve que estar muy pendiente con muchos errores que salían de librerías faltantes (mientras instalaba esta version 5.9). después de esto tuve que descargar el sp1 para mi SO win7 por medio de wind. updates para poder correr el Qt creator; hasta ahí todo mas o menos bien, pero después me dí cuenta que al cargar, crear o correr un proyecto me decía en consola (no importa si es GUI o consola) lo siguiente: "Could not determine which "make" command to run. Check the "make" step in the build configuration." agradecería muchisimo su ayuda a cualquiera que me quiera aconsejar, pues he tenido ya muchos problemas con mi computador, desde perderlo todo (el anterior disco duro que tenía(le instale win10 original) murió), hasta una serie de contratiempos muy molestos como este. Agradecería una solución también dif a reinstalar aunque si no hay de otra me gustaría saber si hay algun problema con esta última versión, y que paquetes realmente debo instalar (manejo c++, python y quiero programar para Android), y dejo fotos del error, de verdad necesito esta ayuda, si necesitan mas información estoy todo el día atento; e-mail, o por cualquier medio. gracias[image: gui]
(edición 1) imagenes del kit y compilador:

```
https://ibb.co/hMyU05
https://ibb.co/jcNp05
```

Comment: Tiene pinta de que no tiene un compilador disponible. ¿Tienes el compilador C++ (mingw) instalado y configurado qt-creator para que trabaje con el por defecto?

Comment: no, si puedes ayudarme con el tema sería genial, eso es lo que también sospechaba

Comment: Emmanuel intenta descargarte [MinGw](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/) y posteriormente lo agregas en la pestaña "Compilers", mirate http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-tool-chains.html.

Comment: gracias, intentaré

Comment: gracias hermanos, todos sus consejos muy utiles, lo logré.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te falta el compilador, descargar una versión al azar de MinGw no es la solución... después tendrás que configurar el *kit* del compilador, que no es algo trivial... y si resulta que la versión del compilador no es la misma que la usada por *Digia* (empresa propietaria de Qt) para compilar las librerías que te has descargado entonces el editor no te va a dejar compilar.

Lo más sencillo es arrancar la herramienta de mantenimiento (búscala en la carpeta Qt del menú inicio) y sigues los suguientes pasos:

- Si te aparece un formulario de login presiona "*skip*"
- Elige "*añadir o eliminar componentes*"
- Te aparecerá un arbol con las diferentes versiones de Qt disponibles... al menos una de ellas tendrá un cuadrado azul... despliégala. Ahí verás qué compilaciones tienes descargadas para esa librería.
- Si no te quieres complicar demasiado te recomendaría asegurarte de que tienes marcada única y exclusivamente la opción "MinGw XXX".
- Después despliega el nodo "*Tools*" y asegúrate de que el elemento "MinGW XXX" (donde las XXX deben ser las mismas que en el punto anterior) está seleccionado.
- Presiona "*Next*" para que se actualice la instalación.
- Cuando haya terminado abre QtCreator y crea un proyecto nuevo. Si no has cacharreado demasiado por tu cuenta y no has creado kits personalizados el proyecto debería compilar sin problemas... si en el apartado "*Kit Selection*" te aparecen varias opciones elige la que diga "Desktop Qt YYY MinGW ...". Si resulta que tienes varias plantéate editar los kits y borrar todos los que hayas personalizado.

Comment: súper, muchas gracias amigo, lo logré.

Comment: hice tal cual esto, me informé y aprendí bastante, que buena ayuda